# NSPredicate not working on filtering array of CLCircularRegions

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, core-location

I want to see if my region is already being monitored. For that purpose, I get `monitoredRegions` from my `CLLocationManager` and then use a predicate filter by its identifiers like:

```
NSArray *regionsBeingMonitored = [_sharedLocationManager.monitoredRegions allObjects];
NSPredicate *predicateForRegionId = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == %@", store.storeID];

CLRegion *someRegion = [[regionsBeingMonitored filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateForRegionId] firstObject];
```

Here is the output from the console:

```
Printing description of regionsBeingMonitored:
<__NSArrayI 0x600000280fa0>(
CLCircularRegion (identifier:'486', center:<+18.45381450,+73.79211000>, radius:100.00m),
CLCircularRegion (identifier:'466', center:<+35.54023330,-97.52949170>, radius:100.00m),
CLCircularRegion (identifier:'469', center:<+35.54023330,-97.52949170>, radius:100.00m),
CLCircularRegion (identifier:'485', center:<+18.56226900,+73.91274500>, radius:100.00m),
CLCircularRegion (identifier:'475', center:<+18.52043030,+73.85674370>, radius:100.00m),
CLCircularRegion (identifier:'468', center:<+0.00000000,+0.00000000>, radius:100.00m),
CLCircularRegion (identifier:'484', center:<+18.55905150,+73.91125600>, radius:100.00m),
CLCircularRegion (identifier:'467', center:<+35.54023330,-97.52949170>, radius:100.00m)
)
Printing description of predicateForRegionId:
identifier == 469
```

But the predicate always returns empty array. Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replaced `store.storeID` by a string constant like:

```
NSPredicate *predicateForRegionId = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == %@", @"486"];
```

and everything works fine. Your `storeID` is a `NSNumber`. Thus, you have

> Printing description of predicateForRegionId:
>   identifier == 469

as output instead of (note the double quotes)

> Printing description of predicateForRegionId:
>   identifier == "469"

`NSPredicate` gives always false if you compare a number with a string. You should convert `storeID` to a string:

```
NSPredicate *predicateForRegionId = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == %@",
    [store.storeID description]];
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Try `NSPredicate *predicateForRegionId = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"identifier", store.storeID];`

Since the "identifier" is a property, you will need to pass it as a Key.

Comment: This is not necessary. The syntax of the predicate is correct.

Comment: Come on people, try before down-voting. If the current syntax is correct, then why is it not working for OP ?

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong. You don't have to pass properties as a key. You can write them directly into the predicate as the OP does. Anyway, the predicate of the OP is correct.

Comment: This wont work @AbbasAwan. Better take your answer down.